# MvvmCross with Xamarin.Forms Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm trying to work through the Xamarin.Forms tutorial for MvvmCross, but am running into a wall.

I'm using the instructions found here:

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/forms/xamarin-forms?scroll=496

The problem I'm running into is that it cannot find the namespace "MvvmCross.Forms.Core".

I've included a screenshot of the assembly reference tree.

[image: assembly reference tree for MvvmCross.Forms namespace]

Am I missing something or is the documentation just flawed?

Update: 
Ok, looking at the source on Github, it appears that MvvmCross.Forms.Core has not yet made it into the master branch. I'm thinking the Tutorial I referenced is out of sync with the actual Nuget package available. MvvmCross.Forms.Core exists in the development branch, but not in the master branch.